# Deleting Buffers LibGdx

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I have created multiple `Screen`s for my `Libgdx` game.
Whenever I exit the game (Desktop Version), I am getting a red sentence in eclipse console, showing **`Deleting Buffers(1)`**.
The number is changing according to the `Screen`, which is active when I quit the game.
What is this "Deleting Buffers"?
Do I have to worry about that?

Also the android version of my game crashes at the second `Screen`, while the desktop version is running perfectly.
Thanks in advance.
Screen1

```
public class Splash implements Screen {  
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite titleSprite;
    private Input input;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            titleSprite.draw(batch);
            batch.end();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            titleSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/Title.jpg"));
            titleSprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            titleSprite.setOrigin(titleSprite.getWidth() / 2f,
                    titleSprite.getHeight() / 2f);
            titleSprite.setPosition(
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - titleSprite.getWidth() / 2f,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - titleSprite.getHeight() / 2f);
            input = new Input() {
                    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                            if (keycode == Keys.ENTER) {
                                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                            .setScreen(new MainMenu());
                                     Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button.mp3"))
                                            .play();
                                    dispose();
                            }
                            if (keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) {
                                    Gdx.app.exit();
                            }
                            return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer,
                            int button) {

                            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                    .setScreen(new MainMenu());
                            dispose();
                            return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
                    }
            };

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
            batch.dispose();
            titleSprite.getTexture().dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Screen2

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {  
    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private TextButton playButton, exitButton;
    private Skin skin;
    private BitmapFont white, black;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite sprite;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            sprite.draw(batch);
            batch.end();
            stage.act(delta);
            stage.draw();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) {
                    Gdx.app.exit();
            }        
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/Title.jpg"));
            sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2f, sprite.getHeight() / 2f);
            sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - sprite.getWidth()
                   / 2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - sprite.getHeight() / 2f);
            sprite.setRotation(0);

            white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/White.fnt"), false);
            black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Black.fnt"), false);
            black.setScale(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 1440f,
                    Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 900f);
            stage = new Stage();
            atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/Button.pack");
            skin = new Skin(atlas);
            table = new Table(skin);
            table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
            textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("ButtonUp9");
            textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("ButtonDown9");
            textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
            textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
            textButtonStyle.font = black;
            exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", textButtonStyle);
            exitButton.pad(10);
            playButton = new TextButton("Play", textButtonStyle);
            playButton.pad(10);
            playButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                    .setScreen(new Scenarios());
                    Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button.mp3"))
                            .play(1);
                    Gdx.input.vibrate(50);
                            dispose();
                    }                
            });
            exitButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            Gdx.app.exit();
                            dispose();
                    }
            });
            table.add(playButton);
            table.row();

            table.add(exitButton);
            table.getCell(exitButton).spaceTop(50f);

            stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
            stage.dispose();
            black.dispose();
            white.dispose();
            skin.dispose();
            batch.dispose();
            sprite.getTexture().dispose();        
    }
}
```

Screen3

```
public class Scenarios implements Screen {  
    private TextButtonStyle buttonStyle;
    private TextButton[] scene;
    private BitmapFont black;
    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Skin skin;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            stage.act(delta);
            stage.draw();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACKSPACE)) {
                    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
            } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) {
                    Gdx.app.exit();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
            atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/Button.pack");
            skin = new Skin(atlas);
            stage = new Stage();
            table = new Table(skin);
            black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Black.fnt"), false);
            black.setScale(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 1280f,
                    Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 720f);
            table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
            buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("ButtonUp9");
            buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("ButtonDown9");
            buttonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
            buttonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
            buttonStyle.font = black;
            scene = new TextButton[3];
            scene[0] = new TextButton("Scenario 1", buttonStyle);
            scene[1] = new TextButton("Scenario 2", buttonStyle);
            scene[2] = new TextButton("Scenario 3", buttonStyle);
            scene[0].addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                    .setScreen(new Intro1());
                            Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button.mp3"))
                                    .play(1);
                            Gdx.input.vibrate(50);
                            dispose();
                    }
            });
            scene[1].addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                    .setScreen(new Intro2());
                            Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button.mp3"))
                                    .play(1);
                            Gdx.input.vibrate(50);
                            dispose();
                    }
            });
            scene[2].addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
                                    .setScreen(new Intro3());
                    Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button.mp3"))
                            .play(1);
                            Gdx.input.vibrate(50);
                            dispose();
                    }
            });
            scene[0].pad(10);
            scene[1].pad(10f);
            scene[2].pad(10f);

            table.add(scene[0]);

            table.add(scene[1]);
            table.getCell(scene[1]).space(20f);
            table.add(scene[2]);
            stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
            stage.dispose();
            skin.dispose();
            atlas.dispose();
            black.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more informations about your `Screen`s. Show us some code please.

Comment: @springbua I added the code as u requested thanks

Comment: You set the `InputProcessor` every `render` loop. Set it in the `show()` method, as it stays the same. Just a little fail i have seen.

Comment: Still the same error @springbua
AL lib: (WW) FreeDevice: (0x7fb9db886e00) Deleting 2 Buffer(s)

Comment: You said android version is crashing when you switch to screen 2. Do you have an error log for that?

Comment: Got it I did not dispose the audio files

Comment: When you do this it does not print the message anymore? Did you also fix the android version?

Comment: Deleting buffers comes from your music file

Comment: @springbua I stored the music files in a Variable.then disposed them whenever I change the Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dispose sound/music objects. You may do it in dispose method of your Game class.